# Traverse CSS hover navigation with protractor

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, protractor

In a CSS navigation where `:hover` expands a sub-level and click does not. Clicking a top-level item instead causes a view change. How can I traverse such a navigation with protractor?

(This is somewhat pseudo code)

eg.

```
it 'should do things', ->
  Page.login(browser, '/#/area')
  .then ->
    # Here I need to expand the navigation in order to
    # make the sub-menu visible. Hover 1500ms.
    UI.menu.hover('1500')
  .then ->
    expect(UI.menu.submenu.visible()).to.be.true
    UI.menu.submenu.item.click()
  .then ->
    expect(something()).to.be.true
```

Is this possible with protractor?

I've read a bit about `action()` [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/159) but I couldn't really conclude what the result was.

---

- AngularJS 1.2.16
- Protractor 0.22.0
- CoffeeScript

Comment: Do remember that hover is very mobile-unfriendly. Therefore, it's worth thinking if it's the best UX solution in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @firstdoit - though this application is not meant to support any device beyond desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebDriver's actions is the way to go. After moving the mouse to the right element, you can wait there for Xms which means you're hovering an element.

*CoffeeScript:*

```
hoverEl = (el, duration) ->
  browser.driver.actions().
    mouseMove(el).
    perform()
  .then ->
    browser.driver.wait ->
      setTimeout(->
        return true
      , duration)
```

*Or regular js:*

```
var hoverEl;

hoverEl = function(el, duration) {
  return browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(el).perform().then(function() {
    return browser.driver.wait(function() {
      return setTimeout(function() {
        return true;
      }, duration);
    });
  });
};
```

[< Protractors docs on actions >](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions)